# django raw query return non-ordered dict position according to select query

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a query, for example `select a, b, c, d from table`. why does the dict return sometimes [{'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'d': 4}] ....] etc. I want it [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, ....] according to the position in the select query.

```
db.execute(query)
data = dictfetchall(db)
```

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    # Return all rows from a cursor as a dict
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: python version 3.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dicts keys have been unordered in Python until version 3.6, where CPython's dict implementation keeps the insertion order, and in Python 3.7 dict order became officially guaranteed.

Since you're using Python 3.5, where dict keys are unordered, a typical alternative is to use `collections.OrderedDict` instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def dictfetchall(cursor):
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        OrderedDict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```